# Executar JS ao abrir a página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa noite. Tenho um js onde preciso que seja executado ao carregar a página. Ele funciona quando clico, mas não consigo fazer com que o calculo seja feito automaticamente ao carregar a página.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    executa5();
    $(".cubagem, .tabbable").on('click mouseover load', executa5);

        function executa5(){
            valorTotaldaNota    = $("#valorTotaldaNota").val();
            valorTotaldaNota    = valorTotaldaNota.replace(".", "");
            valorTotaldaNota    = valorTotaldaNota.replace(",", ".");
            adValorem           = $("#adValorem").val();
            gris                = $("#gris").val();

            v1   = valorTotaldaNota * adValorem / 100;
            v2   = valorTotaldaNota * gris / 100;
            v1v2 = v1+v2;

            $("#valordoSeguro").val( v1v2.toFixed(2) );
    };  
});
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: verificou o inspetor de elemento para ver se não ocorreu algum erro?

Comment: declara sua função `executa5` fora do .ready

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Posta isso como resposta

Comment: é só uma sugestão, se resolver eu transformo em resposta :)

Comment: Fiz, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Você fez o que o Guilherme disse? Provavelmente sua função está dando algum erro e está parando

Comment: Como eu verifico no inspetor para ver se tem algum erro?

Comment: Botão direito do mouse, inspecionar elemento, vai abrir umas paradas procura pela aba console e analisa os erros.

Comment: Não tem erro nenhum aparecendo no inspetor

Answer (score 1):

**Tiago**, não há nada de errado com sua lógica (http://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/8mdky0zk/1/)

Outro código está impedindo a finalização (ou seja, a função é guardada na memória mas o documento não fica pronto).

Para debugar usando o inspetor, vá até a aba **Sources**, escolha o documento contendo o javascript e adicione um break point na chamada de:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
executa5(); // <-- adicione o break point aqui
```

Em seguida atualize a página veja se a chamada executa5() é passada no carregamento. Se não for, insira o break point em outro momento do javascript e verifique assim sucessivamente onde o código não passa mais. Faça passo a passo teclando **F11** e **F10**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não tem erro nenhum aparecendo no console

Comment: Não é necessário um erro para impedir que o JQUERY interprete a finalização do DOM...poderia salvar no JSFIDDLE pra gente ver?

Comment: Salvar o que no JSFIDDLE ?

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando qual versão do `jQuery`?

O método `on` só foi adicionado na versão 1.7+.
Verifique se está importando a versão correta.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Exemplo:

```js
function executa5(){
  alert("entrou");
  valorTotaldaNota    = $("#valorTotaldaNota").val();
  valorTotaldaNota    = valorTotaldaNota.replace(".", "");
  valorTotaldaNota    = valorTotaldaNota.replace(",", ".");
  adValorem           = $("#adValorem").val();
  gris                = $("#gris").val();

  v1   = valorTotaldaNota * adValorem / 100;
  v2   = valorTotaldaNota * gris / 100;
  v1v2 = v1+v2;

  $("#valordoSeguro").val( v1v2.toFixed(2) );
}  

$(document).ready(function(){
    executa5();
    $(".cubagem, .tabbable").on('click mouseover load', executa5);
});
```

```css
.cubagem {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cubagem">
</div>

<input id="valorTotaldaNota" value="100" /> <br/>
<input id="adValorem" value="5" /> <br/>
<input id="gris" value="20" /> <br/>
<input id="valordoSeguro" />
```

Comment: Minha versão de jQuery é 2.0.3

Comment: @Tiago Me mostra como você está importando

Comment: Como assim amigo, importando?

Comment: Como você está chamando o arquivo js do jQuery?

Comment: Esta no final do arquivo php

Comment: Antes ou depois do seu `$(document).ready(function...`?

Comment: Aparece depois.

Comment: Coloque antes dele

Comment: Nada, não mesma coisa. Eu utilizo o DW, existe algum programa ou extensão para debugar e tentar ver onde esta o erro?

Comment: Me cola a linha que você adiciona o jQuery ao site

Comment: <script src='assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'>

Comment: Duas coisas, verifica se no mesmo diretório que está sua página é o diretório que tem a pasta assets. E fecha a tag </script>

Comment: Esta fechada. Tudo funciona no sistema. menos isso que estou tentando fazer agora. Estranho isso!

Comment: Verificou se no mesmo diretório que está sua página é o diretório que tem a pasta assets?

Comment: Sim, estão no mesmo diretorio